# Error inflating menu in Android

Tags: java, android, menu

Hello i learn to use menu in Android. And i set minimum SDK = 8 and Maximum SDK = 17.
I want when the Application run in minimum SDK the menu show at the bottom. And in latest SDK show menu on top of application bar.

But it was error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidmenu/com.example.androidmenu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class menu
```

Here is my **menu.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
        android:title="Save"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:title="Search"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
        android:text="Delete"/>

</menu>
```

And here is my **MainActivity.java** file

```
package com.example.androidmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Event Handling for individual menu
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_save:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search selected:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Thank you :)

Comment: do you have a layout by the name menu?

Comment: It should be `R.menu.menu` if it is in your `menu` folder

Comment: ooh, i think my menu.xml is my layout too. I change `R.layout.menu` to `R.layout.activity_main` it works now. :D
But the icon not show in latest SDK.

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

To

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); // assuming menu.xml in /res/menu/menu.xml
```

Also do you have a layout like `menu.xml` if so rename it to avoid confusion to `activity_main.xml`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // res/layout/activity_main.xml
```

You can check the docs. has code snippets

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: @fanjavaid if it is a layout rename it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:text="Delete"` to `android:title="Delete"` in your last menu item.

Comment: Thanks it fix my last missing text menu :D